# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "braintree_payment": in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am getting an error like this while using braintree_payment package for ios.

I tried to run this command `pod install --repo-update`

I get

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "braintree_payment":
  In Podfile:
    braintree_payment (from `.symlinks/plugins/braintree_payment/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `braintree_payment (from `.symlinks/plugins/braintree_payment/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Any solutions to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

edit `Podfile` & add at top of file `platform :ios, '12.0'`

https://github.com/pikaju/flutter-braintree/issues/85